# Did Joseph Goebbels say "Accuse the other side of that which you are guilty"?

Tags: quotes, nazi-germany, joseph-goebbels

The quote, "accuse the other side of that which you are guilty" is often attributed to [Joseph Goebbels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Goebbels).

For example [this meme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxC4x.png) and it also appears in [me.me](https://me.me/i/accuse-the-other-side-of-that-which-you-are-guilty-6778251) and [memegenerator.net](https://memegenerator.net/instance/72467218/joseph-goebbels-nazi-accuse-the-other-side-of-that-which-you-are-guilty-joseph-goebbels-nazi-propaga).

I have looked for it in the wikiquote [entry](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Joseph_Goebbels) about him. I have also checked [this article](http://www.ihr.org/other/weber2011fakequotations.html) about "Fraudulent Nazi Quotations". None of them mention it.

Did Goebbels say this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I was unable to find anything resembling this quote in either German or English.

The closest quote is one from the [Nuremberg rally in 1934](http://research.calvin.edu/german-propaganda-archive/goeb59.htm):

> The cleverest trick used in propaganda against Germany during the war was to accuse Germany of what our enemies themselves were doing.

While Goebbels' Nuremberg quote isn't proof that Goebbels didn't also say the quote in question, a complete lack of any sources at least indicates that someone may have loosely paraphrased him to get a more fitting quote.

<sub>The earliest date that the quote appeared on the internet seems to be in this relatively recent [tweet](https://twitter.com/mcspocky/status/595342875694649345) from May 2015.</sub>

Comment: I find it somewhat ironic that the two quotes most commonly associated with Goebbels (this one and the lie repeated 1000 times quote) are fake.